# Taking the sum and mean of multiple columns and appending the result as a single row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I read a csv file and I want to create a new row with some results as a `sum()`for 3 columns and a `mean()` for the rest columns. The problem is that my output is something like this:

```
Total                   1596260396              
Total2                      30453841            
Tota3                           3.024863813     
Total4                              19742.04    
Total5                                  0.733696498
```

And I´m looking for this:

```
Total 1596260396 30453841 3.024863813 19742.04 0.733696498
```

My code:

```
# encoding=utf8  
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import os
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

df1 = pd.read_csv("este_mes.csv", sep=',')
df1.loc['Total'] = pd.Series(df1['Subastas'].sum(), index = ['Subastas'])
df1.loc['Total2'] = pd.Series(df1['Impresiones_exchange'].sum(), index = ['Impresiones_exchange'])
df1.loc['Tota3'] = pd.Series(df1['Fill_rate'].mean(), index = ['Fill_rate'])
df1.loc['Total4'] = pd.Series(df1['Importe_a_pagar_a_medio'].sum(), index = ['Importe_a_pagar_a_medio'])
df1.loc['Total5'] = pd.Series(df1['ECPM_medio'].mean(), index = ['ECPM_medio'])
```

Some rows of my csv:

```
Cliente,Fecha,Status,cl_fecha,Subastas,Impresiones_exchange,Fill_rate,Importe_a_pagar_a_medio,ECPM_medio
jjj,01/01/2017,Alerta Fillrate - Revenue - Imp Vendidas,jjj_01/01/2017,2277331,25843,1.13,10.36,0.4
jjj,02/01/2017,Alerta Fillrate -- Incremento Revenue - Imp Vendidas - Subastadas,jjj_02/01/2017,6747816,42957,0.64,17.9,0.42
jjj,03/01/2017,Alerta Fillrate - Revenue - Imp Vendidas:  aumento eCPM-- CRITICO,jjj_03/01/2017,6397915,27926,0.44,13.1,0.47
jjj,04/01/2017,Estable: descenso Revenue e Imp Vendidas,jjj_04/01/2017,5764124,22940,0.4,11.14,0.49
jjj,05/01/2017,Estable,jjj_05/01/2017,5635852,23924,0.42,11.24,0.47
```

Output I want:

```
Cliente,Fecha,Status,cl_fecha,Subastas,Impresiones_exchange,Fill_rate,Importe_a_pagar_a_medio,ECPM_medio
    jjj,01/01/2017,Alerta Fillrate - Revenue - Imp Vendidas,jjj_01/01/2017,2277331,25843,1.13,10.36,0.4
    jjj,02/01/2017,Alerta Fillrate -- Incremento Revenue - Imp Vendidas - Subastadas,jjj_02/01/2017,6747816,42957,0.64,17.9,0.42
    jjj,03/01/2017,Alerta Fillrate - Revenue - Imp Vendidas:  aumento eCPM-- CRITICO,jjj_03/01/2017,6397915,27926,0.44,13.1,0.47
    jjj,04/01/2017,Estable: descenso Revenue e Imp Vendidas,jjj_04/01/2017,5764124,22940,0.4,11.14,0.49
    jjj,05/01/2017,Estable,jjj_05/01/2017,5635852,23924,0.42,11.24,0.47

    Total 1596260396 30453841 3.024863813 19742.04 0.733696498
```

Comment: Can I have 5-10 rows of your input? That would help.

Comment: I just added it @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

Comment: Can you open it in notepad or sublime text and copy along with the delimiters?

Comment: Done! Now is it okey? @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

Comment: Okay, and where do you want this output to go?

Comment: I just added the output I want! @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your sum columns and mean columns -

```
s = ['Subastas', 'Impresiones_exchange', 'Importe_a_pagar_a_medio']
m = ['Fill_rate', 'ECPM_medio']
```

Next, slice and compute -

```
i = df1[s].sum()
i

Subastas                   26823038.00
Impresiones_exchange         143590.00
Importe_a_pagar_a_medio          63.74
dtype: float64
```

```
j = df1[m].mean()
j

Fill_rate     0.606
ECPM_medio    0.450
dtype: float64
```

Concatenate the two -

```
v = pd.concat([i, j])
v

Subastas                   2.682304e+07
Impresiones_exchange       1.435900e+05
Importe_a_pagar_a_medio    6.374000e+01
Fill_rate                  6.060000e-01
ECPM_medio                 4.500000e-01
dtype: float64
```

And reshape your output -

```
df = pd.DataFrame(v.values[:, None].T, index=['Total'], columns=v.index)
df

         Subastas  Impresiones_exchange  Importe_a_pagar_a_medio  Fill_rate  \
Total  26823038.0              143590.0                    63.74      0.606   

       ECPM_medio  
Total        0.45
```

To write to an existing CSV, use the `a`ppend mode -

```
df.to_csv('file.csv', mode='a')
```